# List all files, folders, subfiles and subfolders in a directory using cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

How can i list all files, folders, subfiles and subfolders in a directory by using cordova? Is there any option in cordova to do this? I have tried using **createReader** and **readEntries** but it shows only the folder and files inside that directory and not showing subfolder and subfiles.

Answer (score 0):

@Abraham,
you might want to read the new docs on FileSystem. Previously, this was a mess and unclear. The newer docs (part w3c, part apache/cordova) are much better.

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file

Comment: I have seen the link. Can you tell me the exact code to list all files, folders, subfiles and subfolders in a directory in **Android device**?

Comment: No. That is documented in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/index.html).